# Why is sign of DC and AC coefficients opposite of normal signed binary numbers?

Tags: jpeg, huffman-code

I am very confused here. Here are some excerpts from ITU T.81;

From section Annex F section F.1.2.1.1 for DC coefficients in scan data:

> "When DIFF is positive, the SSSS low order bits of DIFF are appended.
>   When DIFF is negative, the SSSS low order bits of (DIFF – 1) are
>   appended. Note that the most significant bit of the appended bit
>   sequence is 0 for negative differences and 1 for positive
>   differences."

Very similar to this in same Annex F end of section F.1.2.2.1 for AC coefficients in scan data:

> "The format for the additional bits is the same as in the coding of
>   the DC coefficients. The value of SSSS gives the number of additional
>   bits required to specify the sign and precise amplitude of the
>   coefficient. The additional bits are either the low-order SSSS bits of
>   ZZ(K) when ZZ(K) is positive or the low-order SSSS bits of ZZ(K) – 1
>   when ZZ(K) is negative."

Q1: It says "Note that the most significant bit of the appended bit sequence is 0 for negative differences and 1 for positive differences" but isn't this opposite of how signed numbers work? If the most significant bit is 1 that means we have a negative number, else we have positive number. But here this simple rule is reversed!?

Q2. In both cases we write ZZ(K) if it is positive and ZZ(K)-1 if it is negative. Why do we write ZZ(K)-1 if that ZZ(K) is negative?? I cannot understand this from the documentation.

Q3. Is the sign bit itself actually extra from the number of bits specified in SSSS?

These three things are seriously troubling me and I would be very thankful if you could answer them.

Answer (score 0):

> If the most significant bit is 1 that means we have a negative number, else we have positive number. But here this simple rule is reversed!?

Because you are dealing with variable length data, there is no sign bit. The length works in conjunction with the bit values.

If you have length=1, bits=1 the resulting value is 1, just as if it were encoded in a full signed byte. The rule is not being reversed.

> Q2. In both cases we write ZZ(K) if it is positive and ZZ(K)-1 if it is negative. Why do we write ZZ(K)-1 if that ZZ(K) is negative?

That is just the chosen way of encoding negative numbers. In the normal 4-byte encoding of -1 you would have the binary value

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

requiring 32-bits to encode.

Instead it gets encoded with a length and a single bit: Length=1, Bits=0.

For zero, you just have Length=0, Bits=0.

In this type of variable length encoding, either the positive value or the negative values had to be flipped to distinguish between them. They happened to choose to flip the negative.

> Q3. Is the sign bit itself actually extra from the number of bits specified in SSSS?

There is no sign bit in this encoding.

Comment: Could you explain things with a few examples, that will make it easier to understand. To encode 7 I need 3 bits. However, to encode -6 I will need atleast 4 bits. If I do -6-1=-7 and encode -7, that will still need 4 bits. Now if I read the value 1001, how do I know if it is -7 or +9? It seems that here the value 7 shall be encoded as 1111 and -7 as 0111 so the most significant bit gives one as positive and the other as negative.

Comment: The magnitude and value range tables in the Annex say that e.g values -3,-2,2,3 all need 2 bits, values -7..-4,4..-7 all need 3 bits and so on. I am at a loss here since I cannot comprehend how 2 bits can represent -3 and also +3 and how 3 bits can represent -4 and also +4. From what you are saying, it seems that a bit in the magnitude nibble may represent the sign but this does not tie up with the documentation. Also, if the sign is represented by the huffman coded byte, that also does not tie with the documentation.

Comment: What you are missing is that it requires more than 3 bits to encode the value 7. You need something to tell you the length. 

What is happening is that negative values are being represented with their bits flipped. 7 = 111 -7 = 000. It takes the same number of bits to represent X as -X. This is only possible because we also have the count of the number of bits.

Comment: I made a spreadsheet of all the numbers upto twenty, positive, negative, -1 of negative e.t.c. after studying that it dawned on me what is going on

Comment: This is kind of like the implicit 1 used in floating point representations.